# managing order of threads

Tags: java, concurrency

I'm writing a program in java in which there has to be some threads(for example 3) created from the main thread and running beside it.
the program goes step by step.
In each step the main thread first counts a **clock** and prints it(executes exclusively), then the other threads **all** have to check something( their order is not important and they must work concurrently) to see if they must print out something in this **clock** or not and this repeats.

How can I force this ordering between them in an easy way(the *main* and the *collection of other threads*)?
I have to write it this way, I mean I cannot go without threads.

This is what I want in the output:

```
    Master Clock : 0
      Core 2 started its first task of 7 time units
      Core 0 started its first task of 9 time units
      Core 1 started its first task of 6 time units
    Master Clock : 1
    Master Clock : 2
    Master Clock : 3
    Master Clock : 4
    Master Clock : 5
    Master Clock : 6
      Core 1 started context switch
    Master Clock : 7
      Core 2 started context switch
    Master Clock : 8
      Core 1 started a new task of 9 time units
    Master Clock : 9
      Core 2 started a new task of 10 time units
      Core 0 started context switch
    Master Clock : 10
    Master Clock : 11
      Core 0 started a new task of 10 time units
    Master Clock : 12
    Master Clock : 13
    Master Clock : 14
    Master Clock : 15
    Master Clock : 16
    Master Clock : 17
      Core 1 started context switch
    Master Clock : 18
    Master Clock : 19
      Core 1 started a new task of 8 time units
      Core 2 started context switch
    Master Clock : 20
    Master Clock : 21
      Core 0 completed a total of 2 tasks
      Core 2 started a new task of 7 time units
    Master Clock : 22
    Master Clock : 23
    Master Clock : 24
    Master Clock : 25
    Master Clock : 26
    Master Clock : 27
      Core 1 completed a total of 3 tasks
    Master Clock : 28
      Core 2 completed a total of 3 tasks
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. You say "order is not important" and then "how I can force this ordering" - what needs to be ordered what doesn't?

Comment: If you want to specify thread execution sequence, you can try lock&unlock methods.

Comment: If you have steps that need to be done one after the other in a certain order (sequentially), then what's the point of using multiple threads? Why not just use one thread that performs the steps in the required order?

Comment: Sounds like the ordering is like: A1, B1, B2, A2, A3, B3. The clock increases in order, but there is no ordering within one clock step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on your clock frequency. If it is not too frequent, you could have a shared Object that all of your worker threads `wait()` on whenever they are done with their work. When the main thread wants them to get back to work, it can `notifyAll()` on that same Object. This method does run a small risk of your workers not finishing within a clock tick if ticks are frequent, but that is an issue of thread scheduling that you cannot control.

If you must have all the workers finish before the main thread ticks again, you could set up two `Semaphore`s, which we will call `okToWork` and `okToTick`. The main thread would, before ticking, need to `okToTick.acquire(X)` (where X is the number of workers), meaning that all X workers gave it permission to tick. When it is done ticking, it would `okToWork.release(X)` meaning that it is given permission to all X workers to work. The workers would, before starting work need to `okToWork.acquire()` to get a permission form the main thread to work and after they are done would need to `okToTick.release()` give the main thread one of the X permissions it needs to tick. Note, if you go this route, the `okToWork` has to have its `fair` set to `true`. The starting permit counts for the semaphores should be 0 for `okToWork` and X for `okToTick` so that the mian thread can start ticking but the workers do not have to start working.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's simple and good but there's a problem: In some cases the same sub-thread is run several times( while other threads don't) to release okToTick, so the main thread continues with ticking! Although I had changed the fair value of okToWork but still in some cases it doesn't give chance to some sub-threads to run. How can we force this so that after every ticking all  sub-threads be given chance to run?

Answer (score 4):

I made this using a [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html). I defined a `Clock` class which is a specialized  barrier that updates its internal counter at every step. The tasks are simple threads that do their job depending on the current step, and then wait for the clock to continue.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BrokenBarrierException;
import java.util.concurrent.CyclicBarrier;

public class ClockTasks {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<Task>();
        String[] tasksLabels = new String[] {"Physics", "Audio", "Video"};

        Clock clock = new Clock(tasksLabels.length, new Counter());

        for (String s: tasksLabels) {
            Task task = new Task(s, clock);
            tasks.add(task);
            task.start();
        }

    }

    static class Counter implements Runnable {
        volatile int step = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            step++;
        }

        public int getStep() {
            return step;
        }
    }

    static class Clock extends CyclicBarrier {
        private Counter counter;

        public Clock(int parties, Counter counter) {
            super(parties, counter);
            this.counter = counter;
        }

        int getStep() {
            return counter.getStep();
        }
    }

    static class Task extends Thread {

        String name;
        Clock clock;
        boolean running = true;
        Random random = new Random();

        Task(String name, Clock clock) {
            this.clock = clock;
            this.name = name;
        }

        boolean checkStep(int step) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                try {
                    doIt(clock.getStep());
                    clock.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    running = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                    running = false;
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void doIt(int step) throws InterruptedException {
            System.out.println(name + ": step " + step);
            // Simulate a busy task
            Thread.sleep(random.nextInt(1000));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with a [CyclicBarrier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

The main thread can create the `CyclicBarrier` and give it a `Runnable` that updates the clock. Pass the `CyclicBarrier` to each thread, which will process the current clock and then call `await`.